# If/else statement in Python ArcGIS field calculator

Tags: python, arcgis, arcmap

I have a county file in arcmap and trying to assign values in field calculator based on county name.  I don't have experience writing scripts.

The county field is `tl_2010_55_county10.NAMELSAD10`, and the new field in which I am trying to assign values is `tl_2010_55_tract10.NitValue`.  The type is "short".

I am in field calculator, and have the Python "code block" up:

```
def myValue( !tl_2010_55_county10.NAMELSAD10!, !tl_2010_55_tract10.NitValue! ):
  if ( !tl_2010_55_county10.NAMELSAD10! == "Clark County"):
   !tl_2010_55_tract10.NitValue! = 1
  else:
   !tl_2010_55_tract10.NitValue! = 0
```

Then, in the little box at the bottom that says: `!tl_2010_55_tract10.NitValue! =`

I call the function:

```
myValue( !tl_2010_55_county10.NAMELSAD10!, !tl_2010_55_tract10.NitValue! )
```

However, when I run this, it says there was a failure geo-processing.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in the big codeblock:

```
Dim blah
  if !tl_2010_55_county10.NAMELSAD10! = "Clark County" Then
    blah=1
  else blah = 0
  End If
```

And the just type "blah" (without the quotations) into the lower box after *NitValue! =*

Comment: Make sure the Python "parser" radio button is checked, near the top of the Field Calculator dialog (I'm prone to forget to do this!)